# Component interaction in Angular 2 RC5

Tags: angular

I want to create interaction between components which are not parents or children : they are in different NgModules.
I imagined a service, where  I inject my component, but it seems to not be possible. And I can't inject too my component in the other component (cause they are not parent/child). But they have a common parent (AppComponent).
How could I do to make communicate my components ?

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: I'm searching a case where components are not parent or child

Comment: That's what the linked docs cover as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely can use services. Something like that:

```
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

export class SharedService {
    pushedData = new EventEmitter<string>();
    private data: string[] = [];

    addData(input: string) {
        this.data.push(input);
    }

    getData() {
        return this.data;
    }

    pushData(value: string) {
        this.pushedData.emit(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! Could you make an example, 2 components interacting with this service ?

Comment: Found my explanation here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37579691/angular-2-component-to-component-communication?rq=1 , thx for all